# plotting histograms to visualize differences between two image features

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

[image][image]I have extracted the features from a biometric image, and then applied histogram remapping on the extracted features. I found that this step has increased the recognition accuracy. It has reduced the distances between samples from the same person, and increased the distances between samples from different persons. When I used the *histogram* matlab function to plot the distribution of features after mapping, I found that all histogram are the same for all images and all persons. Is there any ***Matlab plot function*** which I can use to show the small differences between features from the same person, and the large differences between features from different persons, after the mapping step, compared to the differences between features before mapping?
The attached file presents examples. In this file, note the following please:
Images 21 and 22 are for the same parson, while image 63 is for a different person
Knn distance between features after mapping for images 21 & 22 is 394.3704
compared to 992.2379 between 21 & 63, and 993.2462 between 22 & 63. Although this difference in distances, the three histograms are the same.

Matlab codes:

```
% to draw the histogram of the filtered image
histogram(filtered_image22)
 
% to measure knn distance
[a b]=size(filtered_image21)
 filtered_image21_vector=reshape(filtered_image21, [1 a*b]);

[x z]=size(filtered_image63)
 filtered_image63_vector=reshape(filtered_image63, [1 x*z]);
        
[idx D]=knnsearch(filtered_image21_vector,filtered_image63_vector)
 
%knnsearch(x,y)  searches for the nearest neighbor (i.e., the closest
%point, row, or observation) in x to each point (i.e., row or observation) 
%in the query data y using an exhaustive search or a Kd-tree. 
%knnsearch returns Idx, which is a column vector of the indices  representing the nearest neighbors.
% and D  whcih contains the distances between each observation in Y that correspond to the closest
```

[image]

Comment: Without your images and any code, it is impossible to tell. For example, how did you call histogram? There are a lot of settings for it that you can customize...

Comment: The question is edited. Examples and Matlab functions are added.

Comment: Why are you trying to extract this information using histograms? Have you tried simply subtracting the matrices before making a histogram? Also, can you add your data in text format, not as images?

Comment: How can I add text files? only images are allowed to be attached.

Comment: I have tried to compare the matrices element by element using a distance measure metric, and I found that the distance is small between images from the same person, and large for images of different persons. The histogram of all images are the same. The reason for the same histogram is that we map all features to a normal distribution with a predefined mean and standard deviation. The comparison using a distance metric is done element by element. Thus, the location of the element in the matrix affect the distance measurement similarity result.

Comment: This is why I need a Matlab function which plots the histogram of features, meanwhile indicate the location of elements. not only their probability of occurrence.